# log4j2 logger losing some records

Tags: java, log4j2

I write a test case to test the performance of log4j.

I try to log 100000 records but in the log I can only see starting from 988655th record.

Why the records before it are not written to the log, or overwritten?

This is my setting

```
status = debug
dest = debug
name = PropertiesConfig
 
property.filename = c:/temp/junittest/target/rolling/rollingtest.log
 
filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug
 
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %m%n
appender.console.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.console.filter.threshold.level = debug
 
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = c:/temp/junittesttarget/rolling/rollingtest-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{10} [%t] %m%n
appender.rolling.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.rolling.filter.threshold.level = debug
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 2
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=100MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5
 
logger.rolling.name = com.fnma.common
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
 
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Comment: What is "the log" here? Is it a file? Is it the output in a terminal? Is it a database? Is it Elasticsearch?

Comment: write to a log file

Comment: How is log4j2 configured? Does it use a `RollingFileAppender`?

Comment: I add my configuration in the post.

Comment: With that `filePattern` log4j2 will create a new log file every second, so maybe the missing 988655 log entries are just in a previous logfile (or spread over several previous log files)

Comment: Yes, it is. I have a typo in the path name and the files are logged to other directories. That's why I don't find it at first.